# Porting LineageOs device from Cm-14.1 to Lineage-16.0

Tags: android, git, repo, lineageos

I am trying to contribute to lineageos for Sumire device. I have already successfully build CM-14.1 and install it on my device.

Now I want to port it for lineage-16.0, the problem is the documentation I have found so far is very scarce.

This is what I know up until now:

In Lineage IRC someone told me:

1. Fork the cm-14.1 branch to lineage-16.0, change the required config files, and build in a 16.0 build env.

So, I have forked the repo for my device. Now, I suppose I have to create a new branch from cm-14.1 and call it Lineage-16.0 and start building and beging fixing errors.

The problem is, How am I suppose to configure repo to pull https://github.com/elbaulp/android_device_sony_sumire instead of https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_sony_sumire when building?

Am I supposed to change this line in the Manifest

```
lineage/mirror/default.xml:  <project name="LineageOS/android_device_sony_sumire" />
```

by

```
lineage/mirror/default.xml:  <project name="elbaulp/android_device_sony_sumire" />
```

## Resources:

https://msystechnologies.com/porting-custom-rom-to-android-device/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of searching, I have found the way to continue.

This guide its a backup of the old CyanogenMod documentation, **it seems that Cyanogen was better documented than LineageOs**:

[How To Port CyanogenMod/LineageOS Android To Your Own Device](https://fat-tire.github.io/porting-intro.html)

In order to tell `repo` it has to pull my github project instead of the official one, a new `local_manifest` has to be added to `.repo/local_manifests/my_manifest.xml`, in this case, I have call it `sumire.xml`, here are its contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remove-project name="lineageos/device_sony_sumire" path="device/sony/sumire" remote="github" />
  <project name="elbaulp/device_sony_sumire" path="device/sony/sumire" remote="github"  />
</manifest>
```

After that, `repo sync` has to be executed.

Hope it can help others.

Comment: Did you manage to flash 16.0 onto your device ? I am trying the same with **suzuran**. I have a succesful build but a black screen ^^.

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not :(

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently working on the same device sumire and I'm trying to get lineageos 17.1 working on this device. Maybe you can give me some tips on this or even we can get in contact if you are still interested to work on this project.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is more of a comment. You can also start a discussion in StackOverflow by having comments under the question. You should always add comments in the dedicated section. Thank you.